# Unable to resolve class in C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle

[Many unresolved class in "C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AOl5.png)

I'm still new to Flutter, and I'm unsure about what went wrong in this file "C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle". I've already searched for a solution, but unfortunately, I couldn't find one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.